# Determine the distance between black and white pixels in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I'm planning on using JavaScript for this project (but I'm willing to use something else). I load an image in javascript and when I place a point on the image I want to calculate the x and y distance from the placed point to the first black or grey pixel.

[image: Example Image]

So I place the red dot on the image, then I want to show the user the x, y distance from the selected point to the first black pixel. The distance can be in pixels (I dont mind). Is this possible and can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the image to a canvas by using [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#drawImage) as seen in this [MDN example.](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/3_1_canvas_drawimage.html) Then extract the pixel data by using [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context), which returns an object containing `width`, `height` and `data` properties.

The `data` property is a sequence of rgba (red, green, blue, alpha) values that run from the left to right per row of pixels. The values are from 0-255. For transparency, 0 means the pixel is transparent, 255 means opaque.

The array looks like this:

```
    ,--- first pixel (top left)
    |       ,-- second pixel
____|___ ___|___    _______,--- last pixel (bottom right)
[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...,r,g,b,a]
```

Given the width and height of the canvas context, you can use some not-so-complex math to get pixels at (x,y) or just run through some nested loops, you can find your pixels at any given (x,y).

As for finding the closest black pixel, I suggest you start from your pixel at (x,y) and increment/decrement x,y or both to get the surrounding pixels. The fastest way I can think of is to run through pixels for one direction until you hit a pixel you want. Do this for the other directions. Then compare values.

An example of getting neighboring pixels 1 pixel away from the "red pixel", in a cartesian plane. You can omit diagonals if you only want horizontal and vertical.

```
/*(x-1,y+1)*/ ( x ,y+1) /*(x+1,y+1)*/
  (x-1, y )   ( x , y )   (x+1, y )
/*(x-1,y-1)*/ ( x ,y-1) /*(x+1,y-1)*/
```

For distance, given the "red pixel"'s (x,y) and the nearest black pixel's (x,y), you can use [one of many distance formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you know a library or something else to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be to use the `getImageData` function again as @Joseph the Dreamer suggested but instead of searching in directions what you could do is the following:

```
// the context to the canvas which holds your map
var ctx {...};

var point = {x:x, y:y};
// this gets a 3 by 3 bitmap data from your canvas with the centre being your point
var search = ctx.getImageData(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);

var match = false;
while(!match)
{
    // iterate over the search array looking for a black or grey pixel
    // and add the co ordinates of the matches into another array

    // if we found matches in this loop, calculate the shortest length match
    // and then break out of the loop

    // otherwise get a bigger sample data to search through and do this loop again
    // you could optimise this by skipping the pixels you looked through
    // in the previous loop
}
```